# regular expression to find a string that always contains 6 characters, CAPITALS and numbers only

Tags: regex

I've been trying to catch a string (6 characters) like `ABC123` (or any combination of Capitals and numbers) using a regular expression. I can catch `ABCDE1` or `1ABCDE` or even `AC34FG`. As long as the string contains at least 1 CAPITAL **and** 1 number the regular expression works just fine. But something like `ABCDEF` or `123456` does not! What am I missing? The regular expression I use is:

```
(?<=\t)([0-9]+[A-Z]+|[A-Z]+[0-9]+)[0-9A-Z]*(?=\t)
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Try `(?<![^\t])[0-9A-Z]{6}(?![^\t])`

Comment: `^(?=.*[[:alpha:]])(?=.*[[:digit:]])[[:alnum:]]{6}$` or `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-z0-9]{6}$` with the `i` modifier (case insensitive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `(?<=\t)([0-9]+[A-Z]+|[A-Z]+[0-9]+)[0-9A-Z]*(?=\t)` pattern, you explicitly require at least 1 digit to be followed with at least 1 letter (with `[0-9]+[A-Z]+`) (and vice versa with `[A-Z]+[0-9]+`) only in between tab chars.

To just match any 6 char substring in between tabs that consists of uppercase ASCII letters or digits, you may use

```
(?<=\t)[A-Z0-9]{6}(?=\t)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QrJjk4/1).

Or, to also match at the start/end of string:

```
(?<![^\t])[A-Z0-9]{6}(?![^\t])
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QrJjk4/2).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was on the right track but was thinking to complicated. The regex I needed was (?<=(\d{2}:\d{2}[\n\t]+)|(DELIVER[\n\t]+))[A-Z0-9]{6}(?=\t\n)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, your aproach is way too complicated.

```
/\b[A-Z0-9]{6}\b/
```

Catches any (exact) 6 character string, as long as either capitals or numbers or both are present.
Note the `\b` part as a word boundary, you could change these delimiters to whatever fits your need.

Another word of warning: A-Z captures only 26 uppercase characters, Umlauts or accented characters will not be cought here, use something like `\p{L}` if your engine supports it and your data requires it. See https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html for more details.

Comment: OP approach is not complicated, it requires matches in a more restricted context - only in-between tab chars -  than you suggest.

Comment: the boundaries are secondary to the specific problem (and data-dependent - we don't know anything about the source-data BUT a generic solution is easier to understand and edit).
OPs approach IS too complicated, as - theoretically spoken - adapting this way would lead so something like `(?<=\t)([0-9]+[A-Z]+|[A-Z]+[0-9]+|[0-9]+|[A-Z]+)[0-9A-Z]*(?=\t)` which is in fact the SAME as `(?<=\t)[0-9A-Z]+(?=\t)`. Also note that ANY string length >1 would be fine for a match (which is not desired and an adaptation in this complexity is not possible anymore).